# Issue with MultipartFile in OpenAPI 3.0 response

Tags: spring-boot, openapi, openapi-generator

I am implementing a REST interface with a GET which should return a Multipart file. But all that is available via OPEN API is

```
      responses:
        200:
         description: Requested Document
         content:
          application/pdf:
            schema:
              type: string
              format: binary
          image/png:
            schema:
              type: string
              format: binary
          multipart/form-data:
            schema:
              type: string
              format: binary
```

This gets converted to below when I build via the OPEN API generator plgin 3.3.4

```
    @ApiOperation(value = "Returns a Document object for the given groupId", nickname = "getDocumentForDocumentId", notes = "Returns all Document objects for the given groupId", response = Resource.class, tags={ "DocumentUpload", })
    @ApiResponses(value = { 
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Requested Document", response = Resource.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Invalid Request"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "Unauthorized"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 403, message = "Forbidden"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Not Found"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Internal Server Error") })
    @RequestMapping(value = "/documentupload/v1/{groupId}",
        produces = { "application/pdf", "image/png", "multipart/form-data" }, 
        method = RequestMethod.GET)
    default ResponseEntity<Resource> getDocumentForDocumentId(@ApiParam(value = "The Unique ID to search your documents",required=true) @PathVariable("groupId") String groupId,@NotNull @ApiParam(value = "", required = true) @Valid @RequestParam(value = "documentId", required = true) String documentId,@ApiParam(value = "" ,required=true) @RequestHeader(value="sourceSystemId", required=true) String sourceSystemId,@ApiParam(value = "") @Valid @RequestParam(value = "objectName", required = false) String objectName) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED);
    }
```

If you see I get response = Resource.class and produces section shows produces = { "application/pdf", "image/png", "multipart/form-data" }

So all I am able to send is the Resource bytestream only and not the Multipart(info+binary)

**Question:Is there a way to configure the open api yml so thatI get Multipart as the response class in my generated controller classes?**

If I try to manaully write a function with response = CommonsMultipartFile.class and remove produces = { "application/pdf", "image/png", "multipart/form-data" } I am getting the following exception

```
{"timestamp":"2020-03-12T12:46:22.104+0000","status":200,"error":"OK","message":"Type definition error: [simple type, class java.io.FileDescriptor]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class java.io.FileDescriptor and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile[\"fileItem\"]->org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem[\"inputStream\"]->java.io.FileInputStream[\"fd\"])","path":"/document-upload/documentupload/v2/u7677"}
```

I have used the code below to convert the AWS S3 object coming from the backend to a Multipartfile which is then sent as a response of the REST API

```
S3ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = s3Object.getObjectContent();
FileItem fileItem = new DiskFileItemFactory().createItem("file",
                        s3Object.getObjectMetadata().getContentType(), false, fileName);

                try (InputStream in = objectInputStream; OutputStream out = fileItem.getOutputStream()) {
                    in.transferTo(out);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid file: " + e, e);
                }

                MultipartFile multipartFile = new CommonsMultipartFile(fileItem);
```

Comment: It shouldn't return a `MultipartFile` it should return binary form data. You should stream the result and make sure it it a proper format. A `MultipartFile` isn't that.

Comment: I have a use case where the calling service would need the binary as well as the file name. From the backend system I get the bytestream and filename.I want to send them both to the calling service by making it a MultipartFile(Filename+binary). If I only send back the binary, the calling service wont be having the filename

Comment: Again the `MultipartFile` is the wrong thing to use for that. If anything you want/need to return a `FileResource` which is specific for this. However returning a `Resource` directly will likely just stream the result.